# Solidity: Filling a storage array

Tags: solidity, storage, arrays

What is the easiest way to fill a storage array?

```
uint[4]  temp;
temp = [1,2,3,4];
>> TypeError: Type uint8[4] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[4] storage pointer
```

As far as I understand the first line is read as a storage variable declaration, but inplace array assignment is applicable only to memory variables.

Is there a way to fill temp with specific numbers except for element-by-element assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I follow your use case, but I think this has some examples of what you might be trying to do:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
contract Test {
   // A an array held in contract storage (permanent)
   uint[3] storage_array;

   function getArray() public view returns(uint[3]){
       return storage_array;
   }

   /*
    * This initializes a temporary array and then copies it into
    * the contract's permanent storage ref (storage_array).
    */
   function setArray() public {
       uint[3] memory tmp = [uint(1),2,3];
       storage_array =tmp;
   }

   /* This initializes a temporary array that only lives
    * its life inside the method
    */
   function fillTemp() public returns (uint[3]) {
       uint[3] memory tmp = [uint(1),2,3];
       return tmp;
   }

}
```